# Generate timezone aware datetimes using django annotate and 'generate_series'

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to generate weekly intervals from a datetime that account for daylight savings times.

Example situation:
The first_datetime is 2300 3 Jan UTC and localtime. Daylights savings time shift the local time forward a hour on 12 Jan. Target output: 2300 3 Jan UTC, 2300 10 Jan UTC, *2200* 17 Jan UTC, ...

The code that I am using currently only moves forward in week intervals, without considering timezone.

```py
# Models
class Celebration(Models.model):
    first_datetime = models.Date
    ...

# Managers.py
...
Celebration.objects.annotate(
            start=Func(
                ExpressionWrapper(
                    F("first_datetime"), output_field=DateTimeField()
                ),  # Find first datetime.
                end,
                Value("1 week"),
                function="generate_series",
            ),
)
```

Related answer that uses postgres directly: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175963/how-do-i-generate-a-date-series-in-postgresql